# Querystring with int variables vs ===

Tags: angularjs, query-string, strict

In our current project we started using angularjs.
We're facing the choice to either use == rather then === everywhere or specifically parse query parameters to their respective correct type.

Hypothetical example:

```
//someurl.com/search?filter=astring&sortColumn=2

$scope.filter = $location.search().filter;
$scope.sortColumn = $location.search().sortColumn;

if($scope.sortColumn === 2){
    doStuff();
}
```

Because sortColumn comes out of the querystring as a string, the strict equation fails.
I think it comes down to either use non-strict equation or parse strings to ints.
Currently we have a stringToInt() that uses parseInt() with some extra checks on null and undefined, but this feels like we're trying to write C# in js to me.

Can we get ints from search() somehow?
Or should we switch to non-strict in our equations?
Or is there another way we didn't think of?

Comment: How can `search` ever know the type? It cant, unless you want all numbers to be parsed to ints. I'd look into a typesafe language that compiles to JS instead of doing all the conversion yourself.

Comment: Switching to for example Dart would indeed be a way to sidestep the problem. But are you saying that all other people before me either did something like search().toInt() or use ==?

Comment: You could create a mapping of some sort for all parameter names to types and have them parsed accordingly, the main thing is you'd have to tell the search function how to parse which parameter by name, it just can't detect

Comment: Could you just use `$scope.sortColumn === '2'`?

Comment: Maybe a service that wraps `$location.search` and provides the correct types...